# CSS - Undefined height in body tag

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a question. I have wordpress installed locally and making my own website now. I found there is some white space below my footer. Now i see that my < body > tag has a style defined, but I didn't do that.. The style in the tag is depended on the dimensions of the viewport, meaning that the size changes when i change the size of the screen.

Apparantly, the body tag has class names like 'blog' or 'wp-custom-logo'. I havent given these names to the body tag and didnt define a 'blog'class in my css, so i think its standard wordpress stuff.

Do you guys know?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTVKg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEm4t.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Those are Wordpress' "body classes"  which, in many themes, are added automatically and usually depend on the presence of a certain functionality. In your example, if there is a body class "wp-custom-logo", one would estimate that the theme offers the possibility to add a custom logo, or that a custom logo has actually been added.

A possible use for these if to create additional CSS rules whose selector contain the `body` tag in combination with one of those classes and the a certain class that might be present in a child element. Note that *any*  other element except `html` is a child of `body`, so this will actually apply to all elements with that class, but depending on the body class. For example...

```
body.wp-custom-logo .my-special-x {
   background-color: red;
}
```

...will apply a red background to any element that has the `.my-special-x` class IF there is a custom logo on the page.

Comment: Thank you! Im going to look into that. Any idea how that <style> element has snuck into the body tag? Because, If I can remove that style element in the body html tag the problem is solved.

Comment: `style` elements like that are typically added by a script (javascript/jQuery). Most likely that comes from a plugin, but it's impossible to tell any more from here.

Comment: thx, yes i have to say that the wordpress install is quite clean. I havent installed any plugin or done anything else besides uploading a couple php templates dor the page structure. I will look into the js. Thx!